# Display image in ag-grid

Tags: angular7, ag-grid-angular

ag-grid community v20, Angular 7.

I have a working `ag-grid` in my `Angular 7` app.  I want to display an image in a column. The `https` address is contained in the columns `field`.  I've searched ag-grid's documentation and the web and have not found an example of this basic scenario.  Can someone give a code example for the `columnDef`.  Is `cellRenderer` the way to do this?

```
{ headerName: 'Select', field: 'Image', width: 75, sortable: false,
    cellRenderer: '<span><img border="0" width = "15" height="10" src=xxxx ></span>' },
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a multi-step process.

See [Learn to customize Angular grid in less than 10 minutes](https://blog.ag-grid.com/learn-to-customize-angular-grid-in-less-than-10-minutes/?_ga=2.69983376.1419833452.1558037398-1831364498.1557773954)

**Create a custom component. 'ImageFormatterComponent.ts'**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-formatter-cell',
  template: `<img border="0" width="50" height="50" src=\"{{ params.value }}\">` })

export class ImageFormatterComponent {
  params: any;
  agInit(params: any){
    this.params = params; 
  } 
}
```

**Register in the `app.module.ts`**

```
import { ImageFormatterComponent } from "./album/ImageFormatterComponent";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageFormatterComponent],
  imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([ImageFormatterComponent]) 
  ],
```

**In the component you are using it in:**

```
import { ImageFormatterComponent } from "./ImageFormatterComponent";
  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Select', 
      field: 'Image', 
      width: 60,
      sortable: false, 
      autoHeight: true,
      cellRendererFramework: ImageFormatterComponent 
    }
```

Comment: do you know how to return the image name to parent component from child one?